# GGPlot2 to plotly for Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

i am trying to display this GGPLot2 graph as a plotly graph so it can have the hover feature. I am pulling the data using a dplyr dbGetQuery, the graph works with just the ggplot output, so its just converting it to a plotly output that i cant seem to work out :) 
Thanks for the help

```
    server<- 
        output$CSF1Big <-renderPlotly({
            #CSF1Big <- db

GetQuery(connection, "SELECT dimtable3.place, facttable.value, dimtable1.years, dimtable2.kpi
                      FROM facttable JOIN dimtable3 ON facttable.fk_country=dimtable3.uid JOIN dimtable2 ON facttable.fk_kpi=dimtable2.uid JOIN dimtable1 ON facttable.fk_year = dimtable1.uid
                      WHERE (dimtable2.uid = 4 OR dimtable2.uid = 8 OR dimtable2.uid = 7)")


     ggplot(CSF1Big, aes(years, value, fill= place, shape = place)) + 
          geom_bar( stat="identity", position = "dodge")+
          geom_point(data = subset(CSF1Big, kpi == "Research Funding"), aes(y=value*2, shape = place), size = 4)+
          geom_line(data = subset(CSF1Big, kpi == "Research Funding"), aes(x= years, y = value*2, group= interaction(place))) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0),legend.position="right")+
          scale_fill_manual(values = c("france" = "#DA8276", "greece" = "#71BAC0", "EU" = "#70B25A"))+
          scale_y_continuous(
            name = expression("Research Output"), 
            sec.axis = sec_axis(~./2, name = "Expenditure on Research"))+
          guides(fill=FALSE, shape = "none")

  })

<-ui 
box( solidHeader=T, background ="aqua", height = 475,
              plotOutput("CSF1Big")
            ),
```

Comment: Try this: `ggplotly(ggplot...)`.

Comment: i tried this:
p<- ggplotly(
ggplot(CSFBig...)
)
p

The error I am getting is:
unimplemented type 'expression' in 'HashTableSetup'